# Is there a better preposition for this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

This is one of my favorite [quotes](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/h/henrydavid140839.html):

> *"The finest workers **in** stone are not copper or steel tools, but the gentle touches of air and water working at their leisure with a liberal allowance of time."* -Henry David Thoreau

The only thing I don't like is the preposition *in!* ;)

Paraphrasing the idiom results in ...

> *The gentle touches are the tools and finest workers **in stone.***

Is that word fine there? Can we have anything else that looks more natural? Maybe ***"...of stone..."*** or ***"...on stone..."***

If the perplexity is due to its *idiomatic or poetic use*, let's change it.

> *The Chinese are the finest workers **in parasols.***

Don't you think ***"...on/for parasols.*** looks better?

Had it been some *art/act (or for that sake any verb)* itself, I wouldn't have any problem:

> *The Chinese are the best **in paragliding.***

Comment: _In_ is the correct preposition. Check out [Meaning #11 in Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/in).

Comment: @J.R. I don't think so. Is *stone* used as a working tool?

Comment: @jimsug sorry :( I don't buy that as well.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why, so perhaps this will just need to remain an unsolved mystery for you :)

Comment: @jimsug hey don't underestimate the users here. They are intelligent and will come up with something convincing ;) Hope for the best. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: @jimsug It's sense 11. Stone is part of the medium used (more or less analogous to paint or ink in the link), not strictly describing the quality or method of work being done. Thoreau is using artistic imagery to exhort the beauty of natural rock formations by comparing them favorably against manmade sculptures.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName paraphrase it and it means *The gentle touches are the finest workers **in** stone*?

Comment: @MaulikV Correct; one works *in* an artistic medium. *Gentle touches* are being anthropomorphized here by being described as *workers*. Really, we know they are the methods used to work the stone, but Thoreau is being poetic.

Comment: @MaulikV I think I can paraphrase your paraphrase a bit. Hope it helps: *The gentle touches are the finest workers in sculpture.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. I don't have any problem using *in* unless it's not followed by a *verb*.

Comment: No, but tools are used on stone. Think harder. I reckon Thoreau used "in" because he's emphasizing the medium as an art form. He's saying what makes a sculpture great is the finishing touches, not the initial blocking, and he's personifying the tools as he does so. In his metaphor, the tools are the sculptors – they are (correctly) _workers in stone_.

Comment: @J.R. I see. Idioms and poetry need different approach for sure :) Thanks.

Comment: Nah, your choices (*on, of, for*) are all less appropriate than *in*.

Comment: @snailplane we'll chat on this some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A person can be a sculptor *of* bronze or stone, or they can "work *in* bronze or stone".

> "The finest sculptors *of* stone are not [men with] copper and steel tools, but [nature with] the gentle touches of air and water..."

Using "of" instead affects the meaning by shifting the focus from the tools to the force that wields them (this distinction was mentioned in a previous response). Is Thoreau really saying that people are less skilled than nature? Or is his intent to say that rough tools are less elegant than natural ones?

You could think of the original as:

> "The finest tools for working in stone are the gentle touches of air
>   and water..."

... because their slow working over time is preferable to the quick & rough use of copper and steel.

"In" works perfectly well because artists traditionally work "in" a medium, although "with" is also acceptable.

> He does his best work in oils, while she prefers to work in acrylic. That guy works with clay.

Answer (score 0):

In that quote, the word workers indicates a that it's the tools that are the workers, not people who use those tools.  Obviously comparing wind and water erosion makes better stone structures than through artificial means.

Your paraphrase I would use the word of:

The gentle touches are the finest workers of stone.

But I wouldn't translate that to the first sentence.  Like saying:

"The finest workers in the world are robots" not
"The finest workers of the world are robots"

The word stone indicates anything stone related as opposed to a single piece of stone.